# Using javascript, how can I tell if an HTML object in the DOM is not in the HTML source code?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for ideas on how to detect objects that are in the HTML DOM, but they are not represented explicitly in the HTML source.

As you may know, if I have HTML source that contains the following:

```
<table id="myTbl">
    <tr id="row1">
        <td id="name">George</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...the HTML DOM will add the `<tbody>` object in the object tree without changing the source code, understanding that the source code implies it. So in the DOM, the structure is as if the HTML source had been:

```
<table id="myTbl">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row1">
            <td id="name">George</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a javascript function that is going through the DOM tree, and I need to detect when I have run across an object that is implied, that is, it is in the DOM, but not in the HTML source.

Any ideas how to do this? Maybe there is some attribute in the object that tells whether it originated from the source or not?

Comment: You can't tell.  Why do you want to?

Comment: Thanks for looking. I have some variables containing objects that match up with some of the DOM table objects, except for the implied tbody attribute objects. I'd like to know if the tbody was implicit or explicit so I can ignore/refer to it in the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New idea based on Alex's idea.  Still involves re-fetching the entire DOM, but it's impossible to do otherwise.  You could implement this same logic server-side if it's feasible in your app.  Using jQuery for brevity:

```
function getInsertedElements(callback){
    $.get('.', function(content){
        callback($(content
            .replace(/(<\w+[^>]+class\s*=\s*")/gi, '$1from-source ')
            .replace(/(<\w+)(?![^>]* class\s*=)/gi, '$1 class="from-source"')
        ).find(':not(.from-source)'));
    });
}
```

that will give you a list of all elements inserted :)  May need some refinement , e.g. around the quotes matching `class="` since a quote is technically optional there.  Also un-tested, but should work.

Note that you're getting ***new*** elements back with this method, not the ones that currently exist in your DOM, so if that matters just be aware of it.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I can't in good conscience, give it a vote up ;)

Comment: trashed most of that idea, I like this one more :)

Comment: Interesting. I'm not well-versed in jQuery, but is the basic idea along these lines? 1. Get a copy of the original source code. 2. Change all classes to "from-source" 3. Go through the resulting DOM and find all objects without the "from-source" class. If that's what the above script is doing, I think that will work.

Comment: @Jonathan - That's exactly what it does.  The regex's should work fine without jQuery, which is the only slightly complicated part of it.  One difference - it actually appends the "from-source" class name, though for the purposes of this you could happily replace it and then check `obj.className=='from-source'`

Comment: I think that will work then. There is definitely some heavy overhead to reloading the page, but in this particular application, I can spare it. Thanks much!

Comment: @Jonathan - Note that you're better off doing this server-side if it's at all possible.  It's obviously not for all apps, but you would avoid the re-load of the page.

Comment: @Jonathan - Also, if you happen to need the addition of closing tags, e.g. `</li>`, see my previous answer (click on the edited link and look at what I first posted)

Answer (score 1):

May be keep at the `document.body.onload` the string of the initial `document.body.innerHTML`

Then when you want to make the check, test first to see if they are still the same.
If not compare both strings and find the differences.

I guess this is ok, if you don't have a too heavy page.

Comment: That won't work for TBODY elements since those are added as soon as the HTML is parsed.

Comment: @David, The first time you read the HTML the TBODY are already there.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comment you just need to determine if a `<tbody>` tag has been added by the rendering process as opposed to being present in the source?

If so why not modify the source that does contain `<tbody>` by applying an attribute `<tbody class="exp">`, then as you walk the DOM you know that any tbody node not possessing that attribute was inserted by the rendering engine.